# illegal declaration of subroutine, perl

Tags: perl, file, readline

I'm going through a book and made the following from pieces of examples in order to answer an exercise. I may have messed something up, but it looks ok to me. I get the error: Illegal declaration of subroutine main::read_file at x3.pl line 31. I'm not sure what is wrong here and would appreciate help. The author wants use to use croak so if that is messed up please include it in the solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub croak { die "$0: @_: $!\n" }

sub read_file {
    my $file = shift;
    open (FILE, $file) || croak "Couldn't open $file";

    while (my $line = <FILE>) {
        read_line $line;
        }
        }

sub read_line {
    our %hash;

    my @list = split " ", shift;
    foreach my $word (@list) {
        $hash{$word}++;
        }
        }

sub print_has {
    our %hash;

    my @list = keys %hash;
    print "@list\n";
    }

sub read_file @ARGV
sub print_has
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
sub read_file @ARGV
sub print_has
```

I think you're trying to call the subs? Subroutine calls don't use the `sub` keyword.

```
read_file @ARGV;
print_has;
```

There are a number of bad practices in the code, one of which prevents the code from running. You should subject it to a [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks, completely missed that. It is now doing something unexpected though. It is trying to locate an object method from         read_line $line; Will edit op.

Comment: If it's doing something different, it may warrant a new question being asked. Your code is definitely worthy of being put up for [review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) before you ask new questions. Right off the bat, your formatting needs to be fixed. Editing a question after it's been answered causes all sorts of confusion for future readers.

Comment: Ok. I was asking here because it is making me wait 40min before asking a new question :/.

Comment: fair enough, and understandable. However, there are reasons for that ;) you should be able to post over at review though, no?

Comment: Nope. I figured out what was wrong though. I didn't realize that perl required me to put the subs preceding any that called them. I was calling read_line before I defined it. It was layed out that way in the book so I assumed it was supposed to be that way :/.

Comment: you can avoid that problem if you use parens in your call. `read_file(@ARGV);` will allow you to call your subs before you've defined them. It is common in Perl to have all of your sub definitions/declarations at the bottom of a file, and call them up in an earlier code section.

Comment: Did so and commented. However, the goal was to get a working answer to the exercise. Your advice to post in code review is what required 40 mins. I do not see the reason for the neg.